# using onClick on images to display text

Tags: javascript, html

I should start off by saying that if there is a question like this I'm very sorry but I couldn't quite find a definite answer.

I'm quite new to JavaScript but I was wondering how in a function using if statements you could find out if a specific image had been clicked (Image ID's as 1,2 and 3) and then display appropriate text below it that appends to a previous paragraph.

The var's in this (text1 etc.) just have the text in quotations so they're fine, so I was wondering what I could do to change this code so it doesn't keep printing text1 no matter what kind of image I click.

(Although I think this is due to it being read that if an ID is there it just prints it, so that's why text1 is always printed)

Code snipped.

Comment: ID´s should not start with numbers I think. Eventually this should fix it?

Comment: @chrisツ you are correct, id's are not valid if they start with a numeric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best structure solution is:

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript: changeText(1);">
   <img src="abc.jpg" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(2);">
   <img src="abc.jpg" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(3);">
   <img src="abc.jpg" alt="abc" />
</a>
<div id="div"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function changeText(value) {
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    var text = "";

    if (value == 1) text += "this is one";
    if (value == 2) text += "this is two";
    if (value == 3) text += "this is tree";

    div.innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, it'd be better to suggest a solution using unobtrusive js :)

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById() will return you an HTML element as a variable. When you write an "if ()" statement, some of the few things that will evaluate to `false` and skip the "if" are: `null`, `undefined`, `0`, and `false`. Passing in an object, like an element, will evaluate `true` and go inside the "if".

Chances are, this script is inside an event listener, correct? You should be passed a MouseClickEvent object, which will have a `currentTarget` property. You could either check the currentTarget's ID, and do a comparison, or compare the `.currentTarget` itself to the images retrieved using getElementById. Hope that all makes sense!

Comment: This is the real answer to what was mentioned by OP in this sentence 
"I was wondering what I could do to change this code so it doesn't keep printing text1 no matter what kind of image I click." ... since it is true, and "if" sentence asking for an element will only fail if that element doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to javascript, I giving you a guide for starting. You can probably use this way

```
//first you can a call function on your every image like
<img onclick="changeText(1)" src="abc.jpg">
<img onclick="changeText(2)" src="def.jpg">
<img onclick="changeText(3)" src="efg.jpg">



<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText(val)
    {
         var para = document.getElementbyID('para').innerHTML;
         if(val==1)
         {
             para += "Image One was Clicked";
         }
         else if(val==2)
         {
             para += "Image Two was Clicked";
         }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to forward you to a simpler type of JS, jQuery

Now, how to use the code, you need to have as many images and a div element to show the content. Here, try this:

```
<img src="link/to/file.png" alt="photo" id="1" />
<img src="link/to/file.png" alt="photo" id="1" />
<img src="link/to/file.png" alt="photo" id="1" />
<div id="div"></div>
```

Now you can add the jQuery as:

```
$('img').click(function () { // on a click
  if($(this).attr('id') == '1') { // get the id attribute
    $('#div').html('Image with 1 was clicked'); // write the text
  } else { // else if
     // write something else for the 2
  }
}
```

Simple isn't it? Just update the content on the click event.

But if you still want to use JS then here is the code; just add the `onclick` event handler for these images.

```
<img src="link/to/file.png" alt="photo" id="1" onclick="showone()" />
<img src="link/to/file.png" alt="photo" id="1" onclick="showtwo()" />
<img src="link/to/file.png" alt="photo" id="1" onclick="showthree()" />
<div id="div"></div>
```

Now create a function as:

```
function showone () { // click on the first image
  var div = document.getElementById("div"); // get the div
  div.innerHTML = "Image with id 1 was clicked"; // change the text (inner html)
}
function showtwo () {
  /*
   * continue the work of the functions..
   */
}
```

But you need to make sure, that the ID is present. For example, for your code

And so on..

Answer (score 0):

You just check that `document.getElementById("1")` exists (and if I undestand correctly you have   such an element in your page) so that's why you keep passing through that block of code. The other cases are not tested

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening due to the ID attributes you have used for your images. You cannot use numbers at the start of an ID or class.

For example, the following code will work:

```
<img src="animage.png" id="img1"/>
```

But this will not:

```
<img src="animage.png" id="1"/>
```

Comment: Is there any difference between them both? Please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is:

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="link/to/file.png" alt="photo" data-text="this is one" />
    <img src="link/to/file.png" alt="photo" data-text="this is two" />
    <img src="link/to/file.png" alt="photo" data-text="this is three" />
</div>
<div id="text"></div>
```

in jQuery :

```
$('DIV#images img').click(function () {
    $('DIV #text').html($(this).data('text')));
});
```